# Where can I get wind data for southern China for arcgis analysis? (Specifically Hong Kong)

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm doing a GIS school project where I have to use the GIS software to locate and assess a suitable area for an offshore windfarm. As I live in Hong Kong city (Southern China), I'm going to base my project around the coastal area of the city. But I'm having a really hard time finding data that will allow me to map out wind speed and/or wind density so that I can produce contour maps like the one below. Help is much appreciated. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You can ask Hong Kong Observatory directly at http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/reqform_e.htm